# Download xml file from the server with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, xml, httprequest

am trying to download a xml file from public data bank 
`http://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL?downloadformat=xml`
I tried to do it with requests:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url)
response.encoding = 'utf-8' #or response.apparent_encoding
print(response.content)
```

and wget

```
import wget
wget.download(url, './my.xml')
```

But both of the ways provide mess instead of a correct file (it looks like a broken encoding, but I cannot fix it)
If I try to download the file via web browser I get correct a UTF-8 xml file.
What am I doing wrong in the code?

Comment: the link you shared provides a ZIP file. So how could it be in a wrong encoding?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, thank you. My Mac was extracting it implicitly so I didn't notice that it is actually zip. Shame on me!